# Better design of my current algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, compare, computer-science

I'm designing an algorithm to compare two objects, I've got a formula, but I don't know if it's as good as it could be.

essentialy, i'm comparing tropes between two games to say how similar they are:

```
$divisor = ((count($similar_concepts) - $iterator) + ($total - $iterator) + ($iterator));
echo "<BR> Value: ".($iterator / $divisor);
```

But, thats not readable, so here is this:

```
 SimilarTropes/( (OriginalTropes - SimilarTropes) + (NewTropes - SimilarTropes) + (SimilarTropes) )
```

I'm just not fully satisfied with the results, here's an example:

```
Similarities: 47
NewTropes: 107
OriginalTropes: 156
Answer: 0.21759259259259
```

I don't like these results because I feel those numbers should yeild a higher percentage of similarity.

I'd love some input here, and If i'm  in the wrong place, at least some guidance on where I should go instead.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you define NewTropes? OriginalTropes? Similarities?

Comment: Two games: 
Game 1's tropes:  'Male hero', 'Big swords', 'No Cars'.  <-OriginalTropes

Game 2's tropes: 'Male hero', 'No Dragons', 'Trains' <-New Tropes 

Similarities:  'Male hero'. 

Make sense?

Comment: I'm thinking Cosine Similarity is something I'll need to use here, but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: So you're calling `Game 1` the "original" and `Game 2` the "new" and then you're finding the union?

Comment: That's nearly it, but I think just finding what elements are between them is folly, because consider for example if Game 2 has VERY few tropes?  And maybe all the tropes in Game 2 match up to a few in Game 1.  Whereas say a different Game 2 has many, many tropes, and only a small percentage could match up.

Comment: An ideal comparison would not only take into account the individual size of each set, but also whether these two sets have anything in common. Treat them like vectors. Using the formal rules of an `N`-dimensional vector, their dot product is zero when they are orthogonal (no items in common) when they have many items in common, their dot product is large. See my answer below, which is a more formal example of the cosine similarity I'm describing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Translation to Mathematics

Let me (attempt) to translate what you have into something of a more mathematical formula. It should be easier from there.

`OriginalTropes` is the number of tropes from some game, call it `A`. Then `NewTropes` is tropes from some other game, call it `B`. Then `Similarities` is simply the intersection of `A` and `B`. Your formula is then:

```
|Intersect(A, B)| / ((|A| - |Intersect(A, B)|) + (|B| - |Intersect(A, B)|) + |Intersect(A, B)|)
```

Simplifying, we have:

```
|Intersect(A, B)| / (|A| + |B| - |Intersect(A, B)|)
```

In other words, you're saying that the similarity is the ratio between the number of common items divided by the total number of items minus the number of items in common.

Now let's take a couple of special cases. Take `A = B`. Then we have:

`|Intersect(A, B)| = |A| = |B|`. Your formula is then:

```
|A| / (|A| + |A| - |A|) = 1
```

## Limitations

Let's say now that the sets `A` and `B` are equal in size. But, they only have half of their items in common. In other words,

```
|A| = |B| = 2 |Intersect(A, B)|
```

You similarity score is then:

```
1/2 |A| / (2|A| - 1/2|A|) = 1/3
```

Ideally, this should be `1/2`, not `1/3`. You get something similar if you consider any sets where `|A| = |B| = n` and where `|Intersect(A, B)| = n * p` for `0 <= p <= 1`.

In general, for sets of the above form you end up with your similarity algorithm underestimating the similarity between the two sets. This looks something like the purple curve in the image below. The blue curve is what cosine similarity would give. So if 50% are common and they are equal size, the two sets have a similarity of `0.5`. Likewise, if they have 90% in common then it has a similarity of `0.9`.

[image]

## Cosine Similarity

What you may wish for is something similar to the angle between the two sets. Consider the total set of elements, `Intersect(A, B)` and define `N = |Intersect(A, B)|`. Let `a` and `b` be an `N` dimensional representation of `A` and `B`, where each element has value `1` if present in the original set or `0` if not.

Then you use the cosine of the angle as:

`Cos(theta) = Dot(a, b) / (||a|| * ||b||)`

Note that the notation `||a||` refers to the euclidean length, not the size of the set. This may have better properties than what you were using before.

## Example

Here's an example. Let's say:

```
 A = { "Big Swords", "Male Hero", "No Cars" }
 B = { "Male Hero", "Trains", "No Dragons" }
```

Then the full *distinct* set, `Union(A, B)` is given as:

```
Union(A, B) = { "Big Swords", "Male Hero", "No Cars", "Trains", "No Dragons" }
```

This means that `N = |Union(A, B) = 5`. The tricky party becomes how to index each of these appropriately. You can actually use a dictionary plus a counter to index the elements. I'll leave this to you to try out. For now, we'll use the ordering of `Union(A, B)`. Then `a` and `b` are given as:

```
a = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 }
b = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

At this point it becomes standard mathematics:

```
Dot(a, b) = 1
|a| = sqrt(3)
|b| = sqrt(3)
Similarity = 1 / 3
```

## Sample Implementation

```
public double Compare(IEnumerable<String> A, IEnumerable<String> B)
{
    // Form the intersection between A and B
    var C = A.Intersect(B);

    // a and b are N (C.Length) dimensional bi-valued (0 or 1) vectors
    var a = new List<int>(C.Length);
    var b = new List<int>(C.Length);

    var map = new Dictionary<String, int>();

    // Map from the original key to an index in the intersection
    for (int i = 0; i < C.Length; i++)
    {
        var key = C[i];
        map[key] = i;
    }

    // Set the 1's in the N-dimensional representation of A
    foreach (var element in A)
    {
        var i = map[element];
        a[i] = 1;
    }

    // And do the same for B
    foreach (var element in B)
    {
        var i = map[element];
        b[i] = 1;
    }

    int dot = 0;

    // Easy part :) Standard vector dot product
    for (int i = 0; i < C.Length; i++)
        dot += a[i] * b[i];

    // It suffices to take the length because the euclidean norm
    // of a and b are, respectively, the length of A and B
    return dot / Math.Sqrt((double) A.Length * B.Length);
}
```

Comment: I think you're spot on with the formatting here, and I don't fully see the point your making here at the last bit there.  

`|1/2|N / 2N - 1/2`   

Wouldn't this equal er uh. 

nvm, I think I see your point here. 

Ok then Mike, what can I do to fix this? 
`

Comment: @Adola: Cosine similarity is fairly easy to implement and may work well for your purposes. Try it and see if it works. There are lots of different types of similarity measures.

Comment: Oh, I just seen your edit.  I'm going to look into this, I thank you very much, seems as if Cosine Similarity was what I was looking for huh? 

Unfortunately, I haven't quite learned about all those maths yet, shouldn't be too hard, but I'm mostly worried about getting my data in a format ready to actually apply the algorithm.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am having a spot of trouble grasping this algorithm fully, is `a` supposed to be a list of the original tropes?  And if so, won't the `N dimensional representation` just look like `[1,1,1,...1]`, where `b` will looks like say `[0,0,1,0,1,...,1]`. Or something like that?  I'm just trying to figure this out a bit better.

Comment: An alternative to cosine similarity is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index, which the article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity says has different properties - might be worth trying both.

Comment: Good heavens, this has to be the single best answer I've ever been given, or even seen on StackOverflow, Thank you greatly Mike, you've really helped me out here.  10/10, would read again!

Comment: I encourage you to look into other measures like the Jaccard Index that mcdowella posted. The cosine similarity is not ideal for all situations. It really depends on what you're doing. I just wanted to give you a taste for one of it's strengths. The Jaccard Index would actually be *a lot* easier to implement than the cosine similarity. That's the thing with statistics: there's lots of ways of quantifying information. Each has it's own strength.

Comment: After the effort you've given here, I think it'd nearly be an injustice to not learn this method.  I suspect it'll give more quality results as is.  Again, thank you very much, and I'm reviewing this post as we speak.

Comment: I've managed to make not one but two mistakes here. I've updated it to use the correct terminology. I shouldn't be doing Math at midnight..

Comment: Still an amazing post, I wish there was a favourite option!